# Combining div classes and my image map

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Using Bootstrap v2.2.2

I'm trying to apply an image map into my span 4 class, except the image map class is knocking the alignment out (it seems to be breaking out of the container or row class and not scaling the image in the responsive breakpoints). I'm a designer by trade so i lack the expertise in CSS that i think this needs. **There is a clash of code somewhere!**

This is what i have done:

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">

        <div class="span4">
            <h4>
                text
            </h4>
        </div>   

         <div class="span4">
            <h3>
                text
            </h3>
        </div>  

            <div class="span4 map_image" style="background-image: url('assets/img/tradeLogos.jpg');">
                <a class="map_link" id="map_link_0" title="The Guild of Master Craftsmen" href="http://www.guildmc.com/"></a>
                <a class="map_link" id="map_link_1" title="Federation of Master Builders" href="http://www.fmb.org.uk/"></a>
                <a class="map_link" id="map_link_2" title="Build Assure" href="http://www.fmbuildassure.co.uk/"></a>
                <a class="map_link" id="map_link_3" title="Gas Safe" href="http://www.gassaferegister.co.uk/"></a>
                <a class="map_link" id="map_link_4" title="European Builders Confederation" href="http://www.eubuilders.org/"></a>
                <a class="map_link" id="map_link_5" title="Velux Roof Windows" href="http://www.velux.co.uk/"></a>
                <a class="map_link" id="map_link_6" title="Napit" href="http://www.napit.org.uk/"></a>
                <a class="map_link" id="map_link_7" title="Trust Mark" href="http://www.trustmark.org.uk/"></a>

           </div>  


    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
       .map_image { display: block; width: 360px; height: 182px; position: relative; background-position: 0 0; background-repeat: no-repeat; }
    .map_image .map_link { display: block; position: absolute; text-indent: -999em; overflow: hidden; }
    .map_image #map_link_0 { width: 78px; height: 81px; top: 7px; left: 1px; }
    .map_image #map_link_1 { width: 77px; height: 82px; top: 8px; left: 91px; }
    .map_image #map_link_2 { width: 98px; height: 78px; top: 9px; left: 175px; }
    .map_image #map_link_3 { width: 73px; height: 75px; top: 10px; left: 284px; }
    .map_image #map_link_4 { width: 72px; height: 81px; top: 98px; left: 1px; }
    .map_image #map_link_5 { width: 105px; height: 81px; top: 99px; left: 81px; }
    .map_image #map_link_6 { width: 71px; height: 81px; top: 99px; left: 193px; }
    .map_image #map_link_7 { width: 85px; height: 78px; top: 99px; left: 272px; }
```

Comment: Just curious why you're trying to roll your own image map and not just using the standard HTML `<map>` tag?

Comment: That's probably my bad, as i said i'm a designer not a coder, my current image map code was created, i'm open to better solutions. here:http://webpresencepartners.com/tools/css-image-map-generator/

Comment: I think i've found a solution my just adding <map> in dream weaver. thanks for the simple pointer.

Comment: i've come across a new problem using the inline route, the live page mapped areas are not in the same registration points as specified in dreamweaver. so i'm still stuck for a solution.

Comment: Have you tried an external tool to generate the map tag?  Maybe the Dreamweaver tool is miscalibrated.  Try http://www.image-maps.com/

Comment: I've now tried using image-maps.com, and i get the same offset invisible image maps. Which put me back to the main question of having to integrate it into the bootstrap <span 4> div.  Something in the CSS is clashing with any mapping code i put in?

Comment: it seems i need to work out the css to make the co ords relative to the <span 4> and not he image???